# Query all child columns

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following kind of setup with one-to-many relationships:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  children_a = db.relationship("ChildA", backref="parent", lazy="dynamic")
  children_b = db.relationship("ChildB", backref="parent", lazy="dynamic")
  children_c = db.relationship("ChildC", backref="parent", lazy="dynamic")


class ChildA(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  # Some other properties
  parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parent.id"))


class ChildB(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  # Some other properties
  parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parent.id"))

# etc..
```

What I want to do is get a combined list of all children of a Parent instance.
The only way I can think of doing it would be querying each of the relationships separately and then combining them into a single list, but I doubt that's a very good way to go about it.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are all those `Child[A|B|C]` related in any way? If yes, you could use inheritance mapping and query polymorphically. Else, I would stay with loading them separately and combining them (unless the lists are very large and you might need only a subset and/or sort them in some way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [joined table inheritance.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance)